# Django forms и css

Tags: html, css, django

Доброго времени суток.

У меня имеются формы Django:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_check = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
            'password_check',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Логин'
        self.fields['password'].label = 'Пароль'
        self.fields['password'].help_text = 'Придумайте пароль'
        self.fields['password_check'].label = 'Повторите пароль'
        self.fields['first_name'].label = 'Имя'
        self.fields['last_name'].label = 'Фамилия'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Ваша почта'
        self.fields['email'].help_text = 'Пожалуйста, указывайте реальный адрес'
```

При выводе в HTML использую:

```
<form action='' method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Но хотел бы использовать подобное с формами Django

```
  <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="example@mail.com">
```